# Hide and show dataTable column with a button in Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I get a dataTabel with a lot of content. And for each row, i get in the last column a iFrame-Link. Based on these links, the page takes a lot of time to load.
Now I want to hide this column to get a faster loading. The user should able to show the column with a button. But how can i realize that? Here's the content of the column:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show book">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{rollCommunityBean.renderPhoneColumn}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:column exportable="false" rendered="#{rollCommunityBean.renderPhoneColumn}">
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Link" />
  </f:facet>

  <p:lightBox iframe="true" width="750pt" height="650pt">
    <h:outputLink rendered="#{member.username.length() > 0}" value="url" title="#{member.username} - #{member.name} #{member.vorname}">
      <h:outputText icon="ui-icon-person" value="Telefonbuch" />
    </h:outputLink>
  </p:lightBox>
</p:column>
```

**RollCommunityBean**

```
public class RollCommunityBean {
    /*
     * All rendering Booleans
     */

    // For the Phonebook iFrame Column
    private boolean renderPhoneColumn;

    /*
     * All Getter and Setter for the rendering Booleans
     */
    public boolean getRenderPhoneColumn() {
        return renderPhoneColumn;
    }

    public void setRenderPhoneColumn(boolean renderPhoneColumn) {
        this.renderPhoneColumn = renderPhoneColumn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`p:column` has `rendered` attribute so you can control its rendering. You should add this attribute:

```
<p:column exportable="false" rendered="#{myBean.renderIframeColumn}">
```

and add button which sets your property to true:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show column" update="table1">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="true" target="#{myBean.renderIframeColumn}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

In managed bean you should have `boolean` `renderIframeColumn` property:

```
private boolean renderIframeColumn;

// getter and setter
```

NOTE: In Primefaces 3.5 loading of `p:lightBox` is lazy, so `iframe` will be load in moment when it is shown. So if you can upgrade to PF 3.5.

Comment: looks good. But now i get a exception because of the Bean name: #{rollCommunityBean.renderPhoneColumn}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'rollCommunityBean' resolved to null         I updated the code at the top...

Comment: Your bean is not managed bean at all!? Add `@ManagedBean` and actual scope for example `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: Okay, now i get it. Thank you it works almost perfect. My Problem now is, when i click on the button i must refresh the site with F5 to see the column. Can i show it without a refresh?

Comment: I edited the question. I forgot to put `update` attribute in `p:commandButton`.

Comment: Uhm. Added it, but nothing changed... my tabel: <p:dataTable id="table1" var="member" value="#{members}"
        sortMode="multiple" rowIndexVar="status"
        emptyMessage="Community is empty">

Comment: You changed to actual id of your table? See also that I made mistake in my answer I added `update` to listener. Now, I moved it to `commandButton`.

Comment: You're the best! +1 & Accept. Works qool! Thanks a lot!